# Java exponent error at 2^31 power

Tags: java

I am writing a java program to output exponential powers of 2 (by the way, I cannot use `Math.pow()`), however at 2^31 and 2^32 I get something else. Also, I don't intend to accept negative integers.

My code:

```
class PrintPowersOf2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        printPowersOf2(10);
        printPowersOf2(5);
        printPowersOf2(2);
        printPowersOf2(-5);
        printPowersOf2(30);
        printPowersOf2(32);
    }

    public static void printPowersOf2 (int x) {
        for(int i=0;i<x+1;i++) {
            int y = exponent (i);
            System.out.print(y);
            if(!(i == x)) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static int exponent(int power) {
        int output = 1; 
        for (int z=0; z<power; z++) 
        output *= 2; 
        return output; 
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024
1 2 4 8 16 32
1 2 4

1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576 2097152 4194304 8388608 16777216 33554432 67108864 134217728 268435456 536870912 1073741824

1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576 2097152 4194304 8388608 16777216 33554432 67108864 134217728 268435456 536870912 1073741824 -2147483648 0
```

Comment: Integer overflow my friend.

Comment: use `long` or `BigInteger`.

Comment: Is there a canonical answer for this question? Or should it just be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow?

Comment: This is not really a duplicate of a question about *how* Java handles overflow, as the OP seems to be unware what overflow is and that a Java `int` has a finite range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `int` is represented with 32 bits. Thus any value between `-2^31` and `2^31-1` can be represented. Nothing out of this range.

You can use a `long` (64 bits), or a `BigInteger` (a datastructures that can represented all numbers up to the memory limit).

The disadvantage of using these structures (especially `BigInteger`) is that a CPU does not always offer instructions for arithmetic. Thus adding two `BigInteger` instances requires more time than doing this with an `int` or `long`. In case of a `long`, if the CPU is 32-bit, it requires at least two instructions to process this.

---

On a sidenote. A CPU offers a better way to calculate the powers of two: shift operations.

You can simply write:

```
long value = 0x01L << power;//power of two, all in one simple instruction.
```

This works as follow: a shift moves bits to the left. Thus if the original value is:

```
  0001 1011 << 2
= 0110 1100
```

Shifting to the left in a binary representation is arithmetically the same as multiplying with two.

Answer (score 1):

In general,

```
byte 8 bits, short 16 bits, int 32 bits, long 64 bits
```

For Integer(int) you can store a value in between -2^31 and 2^31 i.e., from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

If you really want to calculate powers of 2 without any limitations (atleast as per theory), you can use strings and make multiplications accordingly.

**Edit**:

As Commusoft suggested, BigIntegers can also be used which improves performance over Strings.

Comment: What about a `BigInteger`, arbitrary length, but still binary representation. Better than a `String` since the representation is more compact.

Comment: Seriously, I was'nt aware of it .. thanks for the info .. I'll update my answer